# React stateless component and typechecking React.PropTypes.element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Typechecking guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) describe

> // A React element.
>    optionalElement: React.PropTypes.element,

This is not working for checking for stateless component (defined as function).

I am using

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.element, PropTypes.func])
```

but it is too verbose, and this doesn't limit input only by functions which is stateless components.

Does another `PropTypes.<test>` exist to match both kinds of React Component?

Comment: An *element* is what you get when you either use JSX (`<Foo />`) or when you call `React.createElement`. It seems you might be passing the component "constructor" itself instead of element an of it. Can you please post your code how you are setting the prop?

Comment: @FelixKling Does `PropTypes.element` mean a *component* or an *instance of component*? For example, if I have a class component `MyComponent`, should I pass in `MyComponent` or `<MyComponent />`?

Comment: @FranklinYu: `<MyComponent />`

Answer (score 2):

Stateless functional components does support the same type checking mechanism. Just set `.propTypes` and `.defaultProps` as properties on the function. And here is the [official guideline](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) or you can check [somewhere like here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/237) for usage.

As for the more advanced matching, `PropTypes.oneOfType()` should suffice and you could also provide 'custom validator'. Both options are listed on the same [official typechecking guide](http://Typechecking%20guide) now.

If you feel the syntax is verbose, aliasing with `import {PropTypes as typeOf } from 'react'` may help a little bit. But any further abstraction/aliasing would be out of React's capability because of:

1. React.PropTypes.element is one of the supported type checks which is specific to React.
2. Missing of a standard way of treating edge cases. eg: should I agree with JS `typeof NaN === 'number'` or consider `NaN` as invalid input?